# Is it possible to pattern match with optionals in Swift?

Tags: swift

I'm not too fond of the `if let` syntax with optionals and I'm trying to see if I can get pattern matching to work instead. I'm trying the following code in a playground, but not seeing any output on the `println` statements. What am I doing wrong?

```
let one:Int? = 1

switch one {
case .Some(let numeral):
    println("Caught a \(numeral)")
default:
    println("Nothing to catch")
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A little bit out of context, but: Playground doesn't print the `println()` statements in the right column.
You can write again the variable that you want to read:

```
...
case .Some(let numeral):
    println("Caught a \(numeral)")
    numeral
...
```

In this case you'll see `{Some 2}`.

Or you can open the Assistant Editor (View -> Assistant Editor -> Show Assistant Editor) and read the `Console output` to read the `println()` evaluated.

**EDIT after Xcode 6 beta-5**

With Xcode 6 beta-5, you can finally `println()`, you'll see the text in the right column.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it by use of  **underscore ( _ )** to match and ignore any value.

Comment: `_` will also catch the nil though.

Answer (score 1):

A more succinct way to do what you want with your example would be to use **if case let**, rather than switch.

```
if case let numeral? = one {
  print("Caught a \(numeral)")
}
```

or

```
if case .Some(let numeral) = one {
  print("Caught a \(numeral)")
}
```

*Requires Swift 2.0*

Comment: **repl.swift:3:4: error: expected expression, var, or let in 'if' condition**

Comment: You need Swift 2 for this.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I will clarify that in the answer and take back my downvote, if you don't mind